# I have to add some rows for perticular records.. my project is on live.. so i cant redo the whole database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli

I have to add one row for records where it is not present.. i cant empty/change database, beacause its on live..

for example:

```
id  |  attribute_id | val

28  |  11           | a  

28  |  12           | b

28  |  13           | c

28  |  14           | d
```

suppose this is one record in table of same id, this records are already present in table.. i have to add one row for old records where it is not present..

It should be added like this..

```
id  |  attribute_id | val

28  |  11           | a  

28  |  12           | b

28  |  13           | c

28  |  14           | d

28  |  15           | No
```

see the last row.. i have add attribute 15 for records(ids) where its not present

please suggest me mysql query to add this..

Comment: may we suppose a duplicate combination of id+attribute_id is never possible? (or allowed)

Comment: How you find 15 were missing?

Answer (score 0):

you would get all the ids in need of an insert by

```
SELECT id, SUM(attribute_id = 15)
FROM table
GROUP BY id
HAVING SUM(attribute_id = 15) = 0
```

I am nog sure Mysql will allow this in 1 query like

```
INSERT INTO table (id, attribute_id, val) 
SELECT id, 15 AS atr, 'NO' AS val
FROM table 
GROUP BY id, atr, val
HAVING SUM(attribute_id = 15) = 0
```

but try it

Else solve it using php by getting the ids from the first query and inserting afterwards. (Mysql is not always very allowing to read and write in the same table in one query)